# Using autoreleasepool for objects created in another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I am needing to use `@autoreleasepool` because I Am getting some high memory usage. The issue is, the objects that are taking up memory are created in one method on a background thread, then sent to a second method where they are used to update the UI.

```
- (void)createObjects {

    TestObject = *test = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    [self updateUIWithTestObject:test];

}

- (void)updateUIWithTestObject:(TestObject *)testObject {

    // Update UI
    self.textLabel.text = testObject.text;

}
```

Where would I be able to place the `@autoreleasepool` so that I can release the objects that I have created?

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you're trying to do?  An autorelease pool isn't really going to do anything if you're sending objects across queues in blocks that are just going to be capturing them anyway.

Comment: @dan Yeah, that is likely the problem. It is a complex setup with various blocks, so it sounds like I can't do anything about it without rebuilding everything...

Comment: Need more details, but can you slim down the data that's passed around?

Comment: @NicHubbard We're definitely going to need to see more of your code. Are you running under ARC, or doing memory management manually? For instance, if you're running with ARC, `testObject` won't be hanging around past the end of `-createObjects`, only its text will. This shouldn't be contributing to your overall memory usage, unless you're holding on to `testObject` somewhere else...

Comment: Have you profiled the code and run it under Instruments? If you run it under Leaks and Allocations, you can see exactly where memory is being allocated, to help point you towards what's actually going on in your app.

Comment: The code you show here shows an object created and synchronously passed to another method on the same thread. So it is not what you are describing.